How to Transfer Data from DataGridViewRow to MySql Workbench
I can just transfer all the data, but there is a problem in categoryproces I need to transfer a table with duplicate data there are only 3 values ​​out of 97 duplicates. How do I do this?
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
     if (!row.IsNewRow) // Пропускаем новую строку
     {
         string Proces = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value ?? 0);
         string Cod = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value ?? 0);
         string name = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value ?? 0);

         string query = 
             "INSERT INTO mydb.proces (Cod, Names) VALUES (@Cod, @names);"+
             "INSERT INTO mydb.categoryproces (Name) VALUES (@Name);";


         using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod", Cod);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Names", name);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Proces);

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }


     }
 }
 connection.Close();

}
